# How to run Flex unit tests from the command line on Linux?

Tags: apache-flex, continuous-integration, hudson, flexbuilder, flexunit

I am setting up a FlexBuilder build under Hudson/Jenkins on a Linux system. I want to execute our unit tests, but do it without using the standard GUI-based test runner.

What are my options?

Comment: You already got a good answer below, but depending on whether your server is actually headless or not, you might also run into some serious issues with the Flash Player. I ended up deactivating all of my sound related unit test on Jenkins, because my virtual server does not have an audio card, which caused the player to crash every time... Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folks seem to use something called xvfb. I haven't tried this solution myself so I'll just give you the links to the revelant articles I know :

http://www.benlondon.co.uk/2010/02/running-flexunit-09-tests-on-headless.html

http://life.neophi.com/danielr/2007/12/headless_linux_automated_flexu.html

http://www.brianlegros.com/blog/2009/12/20/using-xvnc-to-create-headless-ci-builds-for-flex-and-air-applications/

http://www.brianlegros.com/blog/2010/01/19/flexunit-and-continuous-integration-updates/