# How do you get FlexUnit output in JUnit format?

Tags: apache-flex, junit, continuous-integration, hudson, flexunit

I am setting up [FlexUnit to run from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280746/how-to-run-flex-unit-tests-from-the-command-line-on-linux) and want to capture the results in JUnit format, so that I can pull them into Hudson.

What are my options?

Comment: Do you use ANT or Maven?

Comment: Actually, we are using Make. We built our own build system to deal with the limitations in FlexBuilder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use ANT to produce my JUnit style FlexUnit reports.  I haven't worked with Make before, so I can't directly help you with the syntax for that.  However, in case it helps, this is strait for my project's ANT build file:

```
<target name="test">
        <echo>Executing FlexUnit tests...</echo>

        <!-- Execute TestRunner.swf as FlexUnit tests and publish reports -->
        <flexunit 
            workingDir="${bin.loc}"
            toDir="${report.loc}" 
            haltonfailure="false" 
            verbose="true" 
            localTrusted="true">

            <source dir="${main.src.loc}" />

            <testSource dir="${test.src.loc}">
                <include name="**/*Test.as" />
            </testSource>

            <library dir="${lib.loc}"/>
       </flexunit>

        <echo>Testing Complete</echo>
        <echo>Generating test reports...</echo>

        <!-- Generate readable JUnit-style reports -->
        <junitreport todir="${report.loc}">
            <fileset dir="${report.loc}">
                <include name="TEST-*.xml" />
            </fileset>

            <report format="frames" todir="${report.loc}/html" />
        </junitreport>

        <copy todir="./test-reports">
            <fileset dir="${report.loc}"/>
        </copy>  

        <echo>Generation complete</echo>
    </target>
```

As you can see I'm using flexUnitTasks to run the tests and the junitreport task to generate the reports.